# Web service call slow from dev solution

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, visual-studio-2008, wse

Ok, I got an asp.net web service using WSE2. It runs on a xp machine.
And I got the front end asp.net application in my win7 machine.

both in Framework 3.5.

In production environnement everthing is fine.

The problem is, when I run the "developpement" version of the front end, web services calls takes forever. And by forever, I mean *eternity*. Here we count eternity in minutes.

By "developpement" version, I mean that I run the instance that is bound to the visual studion (2008) solution. I use the local IIS web server.

My first thought was for a network/firewall problem between my two machines. But if, form visual studio, I "publish" the site to another virtual folder, then everithing works fine.

So I have http://localhost/MyDevApp and http://localhost/MyPublishedApp.

Both uses default app pool. Both have identical web.config. As far as I know, both virtual directories have exact same parameters.

But http://localhost/MyDevApp is terribly when calling web services, and http://localhost/MyPublishedApp runs at light's speed.

It is like this since 3 days now.

Doing some debuggin I can say that :

```
    MyWebServiceRequest request = new MyWebServiceRequest ();
    request.Url = "http://mywebserviceurl";
    request.RequestSoapContext.Tokes.Add (MyUsernameToken);
   //All these previous lines executes correctly, rapidly.

    //THIS is the slow one.
    request.CallWebServiceMethod ();
```

Does anyone have the slightest idea what the problem can be?

### Edit

I also tried changing the virtual directory from my web site's property to something different (say http://localhost/MydDevApp2), with the same result.

### Edit 2

Maybe it can be in cause, the site binded to the solution reside in `c:\Projets\MySolution\MyDevApp` while the "published" one is under `c:\inetpub\wwwroot\MyPublishedApp`. The `c:\Projets` folder is excluded from the antivirus scans, so normally it should be *faster* rather than *slower*.

### Edit 3

I created another workspace (the solution is under team server source control) in c:\inetpub\wwwroot\Other, changed the url of the web project, compiled and run : no problem. So it really seems that the physical path where the files resides is causing this, while the fact of beeing bound to the solution is not.

### Edit 4 (August 19)

Well, it seems that there not much to do. It's been about 10 days since my last update, and now the site under the new workspace is beginning to slow down too. So I moved the workspace on disk, now in c:\inetpub\wwwroot\Other2, and you know what? That's running fine again. Perhaps I will have to move it again in about 10 days.

### Edit 5

I flagged my question to move to serverfault, finally it does not have nothing to do with programmation, as I first thought.

Comment: Were you aware that WSE 2.0 is not only obsolete, but _very_ obsolete? In fact, I think it's unsupported.

Comment: @John I know, but that's not the point here...

Comment: Just making sure - you'd be surprised how many people don't know. BTW, does it even work with .NET 2.0? Just read "WSE is not supported if installed on a computer with a version of the .NET Framework later than 1.1 (or a version of Visual Studio later than Visual Studio .NET 2003" at http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=10854

Comment: These two apps (the front end and the web services) are running on framework 3.5 with WSE2 sp3 since the begining, maybe 3 or 4 years. Your link is about sp2, so maybe it takes sp3 to run on .net 2.0, I don't know. But the fact is that I did not have this problem _last week_, so I'm pretty sure WSE is not in cause here.

Comment: @John Saunders: service packed versions of WSE work fine and are supported in .Net 2.

Comment: You're right. Just found "WSE 2.0 SP3 is also supported on .NET Framework 2.0. WSE 2.0 SP3 does not have design time support with Visual Studio 2005 and hence is not supported when used with Visual Studio 2005. WSE 2.0 SP3 only has design time support with Visual Studio 2003" at [Web Services Enhancements (WSE) 2.0 SP3 for Microsoft .NET](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=23689). That means that WSE 2.0 SP3 isn't actually unsupported until .NET 2.0 is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, it appears that wse2 traces where on :

```
  <microsoft.web.services2>
    <diagnostics>
      <trace enabled="true" input="InputTrace.log" output="OutputTrace.log" />
    </diagnostics>
    <policy>
      <cache name="policyCache.config" />
    </policy>
  </microsoft.web.services2>
```

While the log file was growing more and more, it slow down and down... just disabling the trace solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say without seeing your machine in config, but often times it means you have some kind of a problem with your dns server or hosts file that is causing the process to be slow to resolve the service.

Also, if you are using a proxy server, make sure you are bypassing it for any urls that call the service.

Comment: No proxy, and I don't think it could be machine.config, since just on site (virtual directory) is going bad while others are ok, on the same machine. And I forgot to say in the question that I tried changing the virtual folder from the solution and the problem is still there.